# I can't save files to parse server

Tags: java, android-studio, parse-platform

i'm starting to program in android and i'm trying to save a photo from the gallery on a parse server. but I don't know why, the image is not saved on the server. I was looking on the internet and I do not see anything that is wrong, I leave the code with which I was struggling to see if you can give me a hand and say where is my error:

```
public class ReportFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageButton buttonphoto;
    private Context mContext;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Uri filePath;
    private int GET_IMAGE = 1;

    public void getPhoto(){
   
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GET_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == 2){
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getPhoto();
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report, container, false);

       
        buttonphoto = v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentCameraButton);

       
        buttonphoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},2);
                }else{
                    getPhoto();
                }
            }
        });

        return  v;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GET_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                ParseFile file =  new ParseFile("hdp",bytes);
                file.saveInBackground();
                ParseObject object = new ParseObject("images");
                object.put("photo.png",file);
                object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {

                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

You asked what the exeption prints in the done process, here it is:

```
W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: 
W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:277)
        at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:304)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:134)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:130)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15.run(Task.java:907)
W/System.err:     at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:898)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:713)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:724)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$13.then(Task.java:816)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$13.then(Task.java:804)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15.run(Task.java:907)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Could you please print out the `e` var inside the done method so you can check if there is any error when trying to save the object?

Comment: of course! I already added it to the question

Comment: Look at guide for parse android and test a basic data on database. If data can save, probably your data conversion may be incorrect

byte[] data = "Working at Parse is great!".getBytes();
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("resume.txt", data);

https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#the-parsefile